# Trying to get property of non-object in aside

Tags: php, html, laravel

I´m trying to do a simple blog with Laravel 5.3. *Index* page include aside with categories and tags, and we can filter different post with categories or tags names.

In routes I have this.

```
Route::get('categories/{name}',[
  'as'=>'front.search.category',
  'uses'=>'FrontController@searchCategory'
]);

Route::get('tags/{name}',[
  'as'=>'front.search.tag',
  'uses'=>'FrontController@searchTag'
]);
```

In Article

```
public function scopeSearchCategory($query,$name){
    $query->where('name','=',$name);
}
```

In Tag

```
public function scopeSearchTag($query,$name){
    $query->where('name','=',$name);
}
```

In FrontController.

```
  public function searchCategory($name){
    $tags=Tag::all();
    $sliders=Slider::all();
    $categories = Category::SearchCategory($name)->first();
    $articles = $categories->articles()->paginate(5);    
    $articles->each(function($articles){
      $articles->category;
      $articles->images;
    });
    return view('front.index')->with('articles', $articles)->with('sliders', $sliders)->with('categories', $categories)->with('tags',$tags);
  }

  public function searchTag($name){
    $categories=Category::all();
    $sliders=Slider::all();
    $tags = Tag::SearchTag($name)->first();
    $articles = $tags->articles()->paginate(5);
    $articles->each(function($articles){
      $articles->category;
      $articles->images;
    });
    return view('front.index')->with('articles', $articles)->with('sliders', $sliders)->with('categories', $categories)->with('tags',$tags);
  }
```

In aside

```
<aside class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h2 class="panel-title">{{trans('app.title_categories')}}</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <ul class="list-group">
        @foreach($categories as $category)
          <a href="{{route('front.search.category',$category->name)}}">
            <li class="list-group-item">
              <span class="badge">{{$category->articles->count()}}</span>
                {{$category->name}}
            </li>
          </a>
        @endforeach
      </ul>
    </div>
</aside>
  <aside class="panel panel-success">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h2 class="panel-title">Tags</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <ul class="list-group">
          @foreach($tags as $tag)
            <a href="{{route('front.search.tag',$tag->name)}}">
              <li class="list-group-item">
                <span class="badge">{{$tag->articles->count()}}</span>
                  {{$tag->name}}
              </li>
            </a>
          @endforeach
      </ul>
    </div>
</aside>
```

When a click on aside href to filter tags or categories return 'Trying to get property of non-object'. If I remove *scopeSearchs* and put in FrontController functions $Tag:all() or Category:all() href works, but filter fail, return all post. ¿Any idea why return this error? ¿Can´t do foreach if return one object?

Comment: I think this isn´t the error, if i delete all aside and write for example http://localhost:8000/categories/c (one of categories) works. But if aside exist, when I click in aside href return error.

Comment: I am sure that you are doing something like "foo"->bar or $x->foo where $x is null. I can not catch it here but try var_dumping your variables and you will find it. (To test it, go to php artisan tinker and write "foo"->bar or $x=null;$x->foo;)

Comment: I use dd($articles) in FrontController and return values correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
 $tags = Tag::searchTag($name)->first();
```

When you are using scope function it should always be camelCase

so searchTag() should be start with small s not capital s

You should remove foreach 
use this

```
 <a href="{{route('front.search.tag',$tags->name)}}">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <span class="badge">{{$tags->articles->count()}}</span>
              {{$tags->name}}
          </li>
 </a>
```

Comment: I change this, and return same error. ¿Maybe aside foreach fail?

Comment: Yeah, that is the issue I thnk

Comment: If i remove foreach return Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$name